# Right-click causes application crash

Tags: crash, shortcut-menu, contextual-menu

I have a serious problem with right clicking. When ever I try to open the contextual menu in certain applications like the iWork Suite, MS Office or Evernote, I get the beach ball.

I've completely formated my Mac and 3 days later I notice the problem is persisting. Has anyone ever experienced this issue ?

I am running 10.8.2.

Comment: Is there anything interesting in Console? You could try disabling all services in System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > Services or uninstalling applications that have added other context menu items.

Comment: Are you using a third-party mouse, Apple mouse, or track-pad? Just curious if you have third-party drivers running as well. eg. Logitech, etc

Comment: I've uninstalled the Logitech drivers and also an app which I thought might be the cause. Still I am experiencing this problem. Also there are no Services directories in ~/Library/ or /Library/. Where else can I look for possible culprits?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After looking in /Library/Contextual Menu Items/ I noticed that even after uninstalling the app which I suspected was causing the problem, a plugin was still present. Deleting it has resolved the issue.

The app in question was Antidote by Druide Software.

Comment: Wow merci, j'aurais jamais pensé que c'est ce plugin qui causait le problème !

Comment: Won't the French Académie object to the word "plugin"?

Comment: That fixed my problem too !  Thx

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me. In french, plugin could be said : module.